# Unir dos listas_distancia mas corta_poligonos_Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buen tarde,

Tengo un pregunta no se si alguien me puede dar una idea como lo puedo hacer.

Dispongo de la siguiente ***lista llamada X***:

```
      0          1          2          3         4   \
0  **773331.09**  773268.73  773267.59  773267.07  773266.98   
1  773266.06  773267.43  773268.13  773268.68  773269.28   
2  773266.01  773185.39  773184.45  773183.79  773183.34   


          39         40         41      42       43  \
0            NaN            NaN            NaN         NaN           NaN   
1            NaN            NaN            NaN         NaN           NaN   
2  773286.82  773286.15  773284.52  773281.49  773280.40   

             44  
0           NaN  
1           NaN  
2  773266.01825
```

y la ***lista llamada Y***:

```
           0           1           2           3   \
0  **9963411.61**  9963405.42  9963405.15  9963404.23   
1  9963324.21  9963324.40  9963324.60  9963324.78   
2  9963264.89  9963254.47  9963254.28  9963253.87   


            40         41          42          43         44  
0             NaN          NaN             NaN             NaN            NaN  
1             NaN          NaN             NaN             NaN            NaN  
2  9963266.18  9963266.6  9963266.8415  9963266.77  9963264.91
```

Como podría unir estas listas de tal forma como se describe a continuación [(x,y)].

```
0 [(**773331.09**,**9963411.61**),(773268.73,9963405.42),...,(NaN, NaN)] 

1 [(773266.06,9963324.21),(773267.43,9963324.40),..,(NaN, NaN)]

2 [(773266.01,9963264.89),(773185.39,9963254.47),..,(773266.01,9963264.91)]
```

La lista resultante intento usar en el siguiente script, donde dentro del polígono vendría a ser el resultado de la combinación de la lista.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LinearRing 

poly = Polygon([(773331 ,9963411),(773268,9963405),(773267 ,9963405),(773267 ,9963404),(773266 ,9963402),(7732675 ,9963400),(773267, 9963397),(773273, 9963328),(773274 ,9963326),(773275, 9963325),(773276, 9963325),(773277.821125 ,9963324),(773279 ,9963324),(773311 ,9963327),(773326 ,9963328)]) #grupo de poligonos

point = Point(773614,9963100) # grupo de puntos 

pol_ext = LinearRing(poly.exterior.coords)

d = pol_ext.project(point) 
p = pol_ext.interpolate(d) 

closest_point_coords = list(p.coords)[0] 
print (closest_point_coords) 

point2 = Point(closest_point_coords) 

x,y = poly.exterior.xy

plt.plot(x, y, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)

plt.plot(point.x, point.y,  marker='*', markersize=7, color="red")

plt.plot(point2.x, point2.y,  marker='o', markersize=7, color="red")
```

Intento obtener la distancia mas corta de unos puntos referente a un grupo de poligonos, como su proyección.

Anticipo mis agradecimiento por su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: No veo qué aporta a la pregunta todo el código que has añadido. Para combinar dos listas se puede hacer con `zip(lista1, lista2)`.

Comment: Buen día realice el código zip(lista1, lista2), cuyo resultado fue [([773331.09,773268.73, ..., 773326.25], [9963411.61, 9963405.42, 9963328.89]),  lo que intento obtener es [(773331.09, 9963411.61),(773268.73, 9963405.42),…,( 773326.25, 9963328.89)]

Comment: Por favor, pon exáctamente las dos listas que tienes para que podamos probar nosotros.

Comment: Buen dia, tengo una lista  de la forma X=[11,12,13,14  ;  21,22,23,24] y otra lista Y=[15,17,18,19  ;  25, 26, 27 ,28] y lo que intento conseguir es  XY=[[(11 15),(12 17),(13 18), (14 19)]   [(21 25),(22 26),(23 27),(24 28) ] ]